# Automatic sizing of jqplot bar graph for varying data range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Basically I want jqplot bar graph to be able to size itself automatically according to the data range passed to it.

In my application the data range (ordinates) and the number of ticks may vary, so I need some help regarding sizing my chart properly to avoid any overlapping.

I have tried using HTML scroll with fixed height and width but it didn't work as I hoped.

Also any help regarding X-Axis scrolling of jqplot will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jqplot` does not have inbuilt functionality to introduce scroll bars in case of large data. You have to apply workaround on your side like `jquery slider` or HTML div scroll.

However I suggest you to use zoom feature of `jqplot` as explained [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/zoomProxy.html)

Comment: thanks for your response , i checked out the zoom feature before , it didn't fulfill my requirement . I'll try the jquery slider , thanks a lot for such a prompt reply .

Answer (score 2):

You can get your dataBounds value after rendering using :

```
var minY = plot2.axes.yaxis._dataBounds.min;
var maxY = plot2.axes.yaxis._dataBounds.max;
```

(You can get minX and maxX similarly using xaxis.)

Then you can ask jqplot to use this bounds to plot exact range using :

```
plot2.axes.yaxis.min = minY;
plot2.axes.yaxis.max = maxY;
```

(Again act similarly for xaxis);

Finally, replot your graph : `plot2.replot();`

Your final graph has bounds according to your data values.

**Edit**

You can work on numberTicks as well using `plot2.yaxis._numberTicks` or `plot2.yaxis.numberTicks` (not sure which one is effective)

Comment: Perfect answer for what I needed -- adjusting the viewable range of the graph without a heaviness of the `cursor` plugin (which adds a LOT of extra functionality)