# jqplot pad not working

Tags: jqplot

I have the following code to plot a data from an json/ajax request

```
function plotit(data){
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        $("#jqplot-chart1").empty();
           plot1 = $.jqplot('jqplot-chart1', data,{ 
               axesDefaults: { pad: 1.2},
                title: 'data',
                animate: true,
                animateReplot: true,
                 axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                          label: "---",
                          tickOptions: {formatString: '%d-%m-%Y'}, // ex 02-09-2002,23:09:55 - %d
                          renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            label: "Y "
                        }
                },
                cursor:{ 
                    zoom: true,
                    showTooltip : true,
                    constrainZoomTo : 'x',
                    showVerticalLine : true
                }
          } 
    ); 
    }
```

this is an example of the json response data:

```
[[["2013-03-02 00:00:00","2"],["2013-03-01 00:00:00","72"],["2013-02-28 00:00:00","26"],["2013-02-27 00:00:00","67"],["2013-02-26 00:00:00","48"],["2013-02-25 00:00:00","50"]]]
```

but when i plot the basically i have tow problems:
-The first is that the padding between the top of the plot and the max value is huge, and i want to adjust the hight of the plot dynamically (red arrow in the picture)
The second is that the last value in the right is attached to the border of the plot (bleu arrow in the picture)
![Plot result][1]

Can anyone help me ?

this is the image that explain the problem:

http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/963/sanstitrebtt.png

Answer (score 2):

You can get your dataBounds value after rendering using :

```
var minY = plot2.axes.yaxis._dataBounds.min;
var maxY = plot2.axes.yaxis._dataBounds.max;
```

(You can get minX and maxX similarly using xaxis.)

Then you can ask jqplot to use this bounds to plot exact range using :

```
plot2.axes.yaxis.min = minY;
plot2.axes.yaxis.max = maxY;
```

(Again act similarly for xaxis);

Finally, replot your graph : `plot2.replot();`

Your final graph has bounds according to your data values.

PS : You can work on **numberTicks** as well using plot2.yaxis._numberTicks or plot2.yaxis.numberTicks (not sure which one is effective)

See similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150667/automatic-sizing-of-jqplot-bar-graph-for-varying-data-range/15156180#15156180)